# undefined variable in Session

Tags: php

Please help me with getting the session variable on a second webpage to be retrieved...
on my index.php page a administration variable called $_SESSION['Admin'] is assigned as 'on' or 'off' when the admin logs on.

```
  session_save_path ("Temp"); 
  session_start();
   /////////////////////////////////If session not set, turn admin off
   if( ! isset($_SESSION['Admin'])){
   $_SESSION['Admin'] ='off';
   }

   ///////////////the code to set SESSION when admin logs in

   if ($AdminStringAllowed=='password'){
            $_SESSION['Admin'] ='on'; //turn on admin for successful password
            } else {
            $_SESSION['Admin'] ='off'; //else turn off admin for password fail
      }
```

That works fine, the session variable is retrieved and used on the index.php homepage.

But when I hyperlink to another webpage (these being HTML webpages) the PHP code does not retrieve the SESSION variable, if fact it says it's undefined...that seems to suggest the session is not even existing, but it is when created by the homepage, index.php...

The temp folder shows the session is working and admin"on" inside the strong is showing it's working.

Here is a sample webpage .HTML

```
  <?php 
         ini_set('display_errors',1);
         error_reporting(E_ALL);    


    echo "<p>Hello php ".$_SESSION['Admin'];



   if ($_SESSION['Admin'] =='on'){ etc etc 

   }
```

The Hello php, tells me the PHP is being read inside the HTML file, because of the htaccess file code. But the Session variable cannot be retrieved....

I have tried session start on the second webpage....nothing works
I even tried header location, but it doesn't work either
I tried globals....

I thought a SESSION is already global and should exist across any webpage until the browse is destroyed by the user  ?

Any help appreciated....see image for the details....

The error I get is undefined variable SESSION, or undefined index if I use session-Start() on the second webpage as well, as the index.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `session_start();` in other webpage.

Off course it need to be a .php file.

Comment: When I save the HTML file as a PHP file, the same problem still occurs, undefined index: Admin

Comment: Have u added `session_start();` ?

Comment: I now have no errors , but the index.php says SESSION['Admin'] is "on"  while the second page with code as above is saying SESSION['Admin'] is "off" .... it not reading the variable correctly when if fact the variable is set on the index.php page to "on"...Why it the session variable NOT coming through ?

Comment: Thanks to all for figuring out the problem...the problem is fixed an is only because the session on the second page didn't know where to find the session file, which on the first page is located in a folder.... thus for those wanting help the index page code is written as session_save_path("temp") session_start(); that defines a folder to place your session in, and on the second webpage add where the session is found.... ie add session_save_path("../temp") session_start()....now all works properly...thanks all...

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
```

you forgot to start the session